# Выбор текущего элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите с вопросом, есть код:

```
<div class="class">
<a id="aclass">клик</a>
</div>

<div class="class">
<a id="aclass">клик2</a>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('.aclass').text();
    alert(link);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: 'link='+link,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != ''){
                $(this).find('.class').html(data); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

почему success не сработает на тот который клиент нажал, хотя при клике работает то который нажимаешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас во первых ошибка на второй строке. Alert(link) будет показывать надпись. 
 И функция Success работает. Замените на:

```
$('.class').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('a').text();
    alert(link);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: 'link='+link,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success для ' + link);
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j5qu8Lqy/2/

Comment: Возможно я не очень понятно написал, мне нужно что бы в success ответ сработал на тот элемент который клиент нажал.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Он берет текущий link. Надеюсь, что помог. Удачного кодинга...

Comment: Спасибо заработал =)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)